# How can I grab this id in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, setstate

I'm trying to get React to grab the id from a Button components that are mapped from a dialog.json file. The id is correctly in the Button tag when inspected in browser. But I'm not sure how to grab it onClick.

(After the id is grabbed onClick, it will update the State and present Text and Buttons from the next dialog.json)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import API from '../../utils/API';
import './style.css';
import dialog from './dialog.json';
import Button from '../../components/Button';
import Text from '../../components/Text';

class Game extends Component {
    state = {
        userID: "", //user logged in
        currentLine: dialog[0]
    }

    handleClick = () => {
        alert('Your next Line is: ' + this.id);
        console.log(dialog[0]);
        this.setState({
            currentLine: dialog[this.id]
        })
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        API.getMyDude(this.props.username).then(myDude => {
            this.setState({
                userID: myDude
            })
        })
        // this.startGame();
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <br />
                <br />
                {/* {console.log(textNodes[0])} */}
                < Text text={this.state.currentLine.text} />
                <br />
                < div >
                    {this.state.currentLine.options.map(option => (
                        // console.log(option.nextText),
                        < Button
                            option={option.text}
                            id={option.nextText}
                            handleClick={this.handleClick}
                        />
                    ))}
                </div >
            </div >
        )
    }
}
export default Game
```

Also, any other tips or tricks would be welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your click event to the handleClick function.

```
handleClick = (event) => {
    alert('Your next Line is: ' + event.target.id);
    console.log(dialog[0]);
    this.setState({
        currentLine: dialog[event.target.id]
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try passing `"{option.nextTest}"` as an argument to the `handleClick` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can grab the id in your Button Component. In fact, you can pass the handleClick as props (handler) to Button after a minor change in your method:

```
    handleClick = id => {
        alert('Your next Line is: ' + id);
        console.log(dialog[0]);
        this.setState({
            currentLine: dialog[id]
        })
    }
```

In your Button component, you should pass the id (props) as argument to the handler (props) like :

```
onClick = {()=>props.handler(props.id)}
```